# How to localize JSF 2 composite components

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I have some doubts on how localization works with composite components in JSF, i want to understand well how it works.

So i decided to practice localization for composite components with a little example.

Following the recommendations i created a .properties file in the exactly same folder where the composite component is(A subfolder of WebContent/resources)

```
labelField1 = FIELD 1
labelField2 = FIELD 2
```

Then i used #{cc.resourceBundleMap. to add the localized text to the components implmentation:

```
<html>

<composite:interface>
        ...
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="#{cc.resourceBundleMap.labelField1}"/>
                                      ...
            <h:outputText value="#{cc.resourceBundleMap.labelField2}"/>
                                              ...
    </h:form>

</composite:implementation> 

</html>
```

The problem when i run the application is this:

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /resources/custom/demoCustomComponent.xhtml @14,63 value="#{cc.resourceBundleMap.labelField1}": java.lang.NullPointerException
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.findComponentResourceBundleLocaleMatch(UIComponent.java:1000)
```

...

My questions are:

-Do i need to manually load somehow that message bunddle or this should happend automatically?

-Can other message bundles in my app outside the folder where the composite component is, disturb this one?(I also have a message_en.properties somewhere else in the app, for the templates and other parts of the UI)

-How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filename of the resource bundle has to be **exactly** the same as the component's filename.

So, if you have a `demoCustomComponent.xhtml` file representing the composite component, then you should have a `demoCustomComponent.properties` file holding the (default) localized messages. You can internationalize it with for example `demoCustomComponent_es.properties`, but you should always have a default one in the path.

Comment: Ok i understand. The other localization in my app for the UI, can have its file name changed, just need to add the bundle in the faces-config.xml. But for the composite components that is different.
Now i fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: It does not work for me. I have three .properties files for different languages (and one default without _xx suffix) and the message is always populated from this default property file. I tried change language using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale) and also changing lang setting of my Internet browser. Standart (not composite components) changing of L10n works. Any idea?