# JSF2.0 multi-language composite component

Tags: jsf-2, localization, composite-component

To internationalize a composite component, you have to put a *.properties* file that has the **exact** same name than the component itself and in the same folder.

From the xhtml, you can access these translations through ${cc.resourceBundleMap.key}.

Until now, all is fine and works for me. Where the problems starts is when I add more *.properties* files for other languages. No matter which local is my computer in, the picked language is the default one (component.properties).

This seems to be a recurrent problem since Ziletka also reports the same problem in [How to localize JSF 2 composite components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817888/how-to-localize-jsf-2-composite-components), but remained unanswered.

I have tried all sort of possibilities:

- no default *.properties* file

  ```
  component_fr.properties
  component_fr_CA.properties
  component_fr_FR.properties
  component_en.properties
  component_en_CA.properties
  component_en_US.properties
  ```

  but it results in a:

  ```
  javax.el.ELException: [...] /resources/component/component.xhtml default="${cc.resourceBundleMap.key}":    java.lang.NullPointerException
  ```
- with default *.properties* file plus Language specification

  ```
  component.properties
  component_fr.properties
  component_en.properties
  ```

  only the default is loaded.
- with default *.properties* file plus Language and Country specifications

  ```
  component.properties
  component_fr_CA.properties
  component_fr_FR.properties
  component_en_CA.properties
  component_en_US.properties
  ```

  And again: only the default is loaded.

I would love to avoid having to rely on the backing bean to provide the translations and can't resolve into believing that it is not supported. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This feature was implemented long time ago in MyFaces Core. See: [MYFACES-3308](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3308). The test case done can be found [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/core/trunk/impl/src/test/resources/org/apache/myfaces/view/facelets/tag/composite/localized/)

The locale applied to the composite component depends on the value retrieved from UIViewRoot.getLocale().

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is still there and its root is in the `javax.faces.component.UIComponent` class particularly in the `findComponentResourceBundleLocaleMatch` method. The snipped is below

```
    private Resource findComponentResourceBundleLocaleMatch(FacesContext context, 
        String resourceName, String libraryName) {
    Resource result = null;
    ResourceBundle resourceBundle = null;
    int i;
    if (-1 != (i = resourceName.lastIndexOf("."))) {
        resourceName = resourceName.substring(0, i) +
                ".properties"; //THE PROBLEM IS HERE
        if (null != context) {
            result = context.getApplication().getResourceHandler().
                    createResource(resourceName, libraryName);
            InputStream propertiesInputStream = null;
            try {
                propertiesInputStream = result.getInputStream();
                resourceBundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(propertiesInputStream);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UIComponent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally{
                if(null != propertiesInputStream){
                    try{
                        propertiesInputStream.close();
                    } catch(IOException ioe){
                        if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.SEVERE)) {
                            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ioe);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    result = (null != resourceBundle) ? result : null;

    return result;
}
```

You can see it at the line with a comment that states 'THE PROBLEM IS HERE'. Precisely when it looks for a properties file to load it does not respect any language and/or country code. It always loads a default resource.

**Possible solution**
The 'problematic' method is called from another method `getResourceBundleMap` of the same class and a part of the code you are interested in is marked with a comment (line #1000)

```
// Step 2: if this is a composite component, look for a 
 // ResourceBundle as a Resource
```

Which is no surprise as you need a composite component. So the solution would be to define a backing component class for your composite component and redefine `resourceBundleMap` loading. Below you may find the implementation that respects language only which means it would work for files like componentName**_en**.properties and componentName**_de**.properties but would not for something like componentName**_en_US**.properties

Your .properties files should be in the same directory as the definition of your component

```
testComponent.properties
testComponent_de.properties
testComponent_en.properties
testComponent_fr.properties
```

in your component `testComponent.xhtml`specify a definition class in `componentType` attribute.

```
<cc:interface componentType="test.component">
    ....
</cc:interface>
```

The component may look as following. I used the original code mostly with couple changes. The idea is to override the problematic method and withing the code try reading a properties file for a specified language first and if it is not found, read the default one.

```
    @FacesComponent("test.component")
public class TestComponent extends UINamingContainer {

    private static final String PROPERTIES_EXT = ".properties";


    private Logger LOGGER = <use one you like>;

    private Map<String, String> resourceBundleMap = null;

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getResourceBundleMap() {
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = null;
        if (null == resourceBundleMap) {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();
            Locale currentLocale = null;
            if (null != context) {
                if (null != root) {
                    currentLocale = root.getLocale();
                }
            }
            if (null == currentLocale) {
                currentLocale = Locale.getDefault();
            }

            if (this.getAttributes().containsKey(Resource.COMPONENT_RESOURCE_KEY)) {
                Resource ccResource = (Resource)
                        this.getAttributes().get(Resource.COMPONENT_RESOURCE_KEY);
                if (null != ccResource) {
                    InputStream propertiesInputStream = null;
                    try {
                        propertiesInputStream = ccResource.getInputStream();
                        resourceBundle = findComponentResourceBundleLocaleMatch(ccResource.getResourceName(),
                                ccResource.getLibraryName(), currentLocale.getLanguage());
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        LOGGER.error(null, ex);
                    } finally {
                        if (null != propertiesInputStream) {
                            try {
                                propertiesInputStream.close();
                            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                                LOGGER.error(null, ioe);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (null != resourceBundle) {
                final ResourceBundle bundle = resourceBundle;
                resourceBundleMap =
                        new Map() {
                            // this is an immutable Map

                            public String toString() {
                                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                                Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entries =
                                        this.entrySet().iterator();
                                Map.Entry<String, Object> cur;
                                while (entries.hasNext()) {
                                    cur = entries.next();
                                    sb.append(cur.getKey()).append(": ").append(cur.getValue()).append('\n');
                                }

                                return sb.toString();
                            }

                            // Do not need to implement for immutable Map
                            public void clear() {
                                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                            }


                            public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
                                boolean result = false;
                                if (null != key) {
                                    result = (null != bundle.getObject(key.toString()));
                                }
                                return result;
                            }


                            public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
                                Enumeration<String> keys = bundle.getKeys();
                                boolean result = false;
                                while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                                    Object curObj = bundle.getObject(keys.nextElement());
                                    if ((curObj == value) ||
                                            ((null != curObj) && curObj.equals(value))) {
                                        result = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                return result;
                            }


                            public Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entrySet() {
                                HashMap<String, Object> mappings = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                Enumeration<String> keys = bundle.getKeys();
                                while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                                    String key = keys.nextElement();
                                    Object value = bundle.getObject(key);
                                    mappings.put(key, value);
                                }
                                return mappings.entrySet();
                            }


                            @Override
                            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                                return !((obj == null) || !(obj instanceof Map))
                                        && entrySet().equals(((Map) obj).entrySet());

                            }


                            public Object get(Object key) {
                                if (null == key) {
                                    return null;
                                }
                                try {
                                    return bundle.getObject(key.toString());
                                } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
                                    return "???" + key + "???";
                                }
                            }


                            public int hashCode() {
                                return bundle.hashCode();
                            }


                            public boolean isEmpty() {
                                Enumeration<String> keys = bundle.getKeys();
                                return !keys.hasMoreElements();
                            }


                            public Set keySet() {
                                Set<String> keySet = new HashSet<String>();
                                Enumeration<String> keys = bundle.getKeys();
                                while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                                    keySet.add(keys.nextElement());
                                }
                                return keySet;
                            }


                            // Do not need to implement for immutable Map
                            public Object put(Object k, Object v) {
                                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                            }


                            // Do not need to implement for immutable Map
                            public void putAll(Map t) {
                                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                            }


                            // Do not need to implement for immutable Map
                            public Object remove(Object k) {
                                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                            }


                            public int size() {
                                int result = 0;
                                Enumeration<String> keys = bundle.getKeys();
                                while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                                    keys.nextElement();
                                    result++;
                                }
                                return result;
                            }


                            public java.util.Collection values() {
                                ArrayList<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
                                Enumeration<String> keys = bundle.getKeys();
                                while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                                    result.add(
                                            bundle.getObject(keys.nextElement()));
                                }
                                return result;
                            }
                        };

            }

            if (null == resourceBundleMap) {
                resourceBundleMap = Collections.EMPTY_MAP;
            }
        }
        return resourceBundleMap;
    }

    private ResourceBundle findComponentResourceBundleLocaleMatch(String resourceName, String libraryName, String lng) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = null;
        int i;
        if (-1 != (i = resourceName.lastIndexOf("."))) {
            if (null != context) {
                InputStream propertiesInputStream = null;
                try {
                    propertiesInputStream = getResourceInputStream(context, resourceName.substring(0, i), libraryName, lng);
                    resourceBundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(propertiesInputStream);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    LOGGER.error(null, ex);
                } finally {
                    if (null != propertiesInputStream) {
                        try {
                            propertiesInputStream.close();
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {
                            LOGGER.error(null, ioe);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return resourceBundle;
    }

    private InputStream getResourceInputStream(FacesContext context, final String resourceName, String libraryName, String lng) throws IOException {
        InputStream propertiesInputStream = null;
        propertiesInputStream = getPropertiesResourceInputStream(context, String.format("%s_%s%s", resourceName, lng, PROPERTIES_EXT), libraryName);
        if (null == propertiesInputStream) {
            propertiesInputStream = getPropertiesResourceInputStream(context, resourceName + PROPERTIES_EXT, libraryName);
        }
        return propertiesInputStream;
    }

    private InputStream getPropertiesResourceInputStream(FacesContext context, final String resourceName, String libraryName) throws IOException {
        Resource result = context.getApplication().getResourceHandler().createResource(resourceName, libraryName);
        if (null == result) {
            return null;
        }
        return result.getInputStream();
    }

}
```

Done.

However that is obviously a bug in the Mojarra and I hope it will be fixed soon. Closer look to the code related to the composite components reveals that the default .properties file for a component is read twice which I guess is not a very good idea too, but this is another story.

PS. You may easily adjust te code to respect country code as well if you wish.